# How to rename the index of a Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

How would I go about renaming the index on a dask dataframe? I tried it like so

```
df.index.name = 'foo'
```

but rechecking df.index.name shows it still being whatever it was previously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does not seem like an efficient way to do it, so I wouldn't be surprised if there is something more direct.

d.index.name starts off as 'foo';

```
def f(df, name):
    df.index.name = name
    return df

d.map_partitions(f, 'pow')
```

The output now has index name of 'pow'. If this is done with the threaded scheduler, I think you also change the index name of `d` in-place (in which case you don't really need the output of `map_partitions`).

Comment: Adding: this strategy can also be applied to rename a Dask Series, just by removing the `.index` from `f` function.

Comment: This seems off to me. This generates dask delayed tasks for something that should obviously be immediate. https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/4950

Comment: In dask-world, when to use `compute()` is up to the user. It may be best to combine with other operations.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but the following functions:

```
    import dask.dataframe as dd
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame().assign(s=[1, 2], o=[3, 4], p=[5, 6]).set_index("si")
    ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
    ddf.index = ddf.index.rename("si2")
```

I hope this can help someone else out!

Comment: Just like for the OP, this didn't actually change the name of the index when I tried it.