# Extract converted column from index without losing index.name with distributed scheduler

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-distributed

I need to turn a `datetime` index into an `int` column but keep the same index with the same name, but when I do an operation with the index the index loses its name. 
This only happens with the distributed scheduler. It also doesn't need to be a `datetime` conversion as you can see with the example below.

To fix the index I need to do something like the suggestion in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44337910/how-to-rename-the-index-of-a-dask-dataframe) or do the assign with `map_partitions` instead. Am I able to compute a new column from the index without losing its name, maybe adding a column but passing a meta somewhere? Is `map_partitions` the ideal (only) approach?

**Reproducible Example**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 1001), 'B': np.random.randn(1000)})
print(type(df.index.name) ,df.index.name)
df.index.name = 'named'
print(type(df.index.name) ,df.index.name)
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=8)
print(type(df.index.name) ,df.index.name)
df = df.assign(**{'C':df.index.astype('str')})
print(type(df.index.name) ,df.index.name)
```

**Output**

```py
<class 'NoneType'> None
<class 'str'> named
<class 'str'> named
<class 'NoneType'> None
```

**Versions**

```
pandas==0.24.1
distributed==1.25.3
dask==1.1.1
numpy==1.15.4
```